# HomePod plays Apple-produced news brief, but not iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, apple-news

On my HomePod, if I say “Hey Siri, tell me the news” I get an audio news brief produced by Apple.

On my iPhone, if I say “Hey Siri, tell me the news” I get a remark saying I need to download an app for that.

I do have the *Apple News* app on my iPhone.

I subscribe to the Apple News service, though I don’t know if that is required for this audio news brief feature.